# Remove millisecond and Time Zone from DateTime.now in controller

Tags: c#

How do i remove the milliseconds and timezone from the datetime function?

```
model.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Just format it in the view?  `model.LastModifiedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")`

Comment: Do you mean set the milliseconds to `0` and the timezone to `unspecified`?

Comment: You can simply write zero to the miiliseconds property.  You never remove timezone.  All time in every computer stores the datatime as a number in UTF.  You correct for differences in time zones either when outputting the datetime, or when you enter time as a string that was generated in a different timezone from the setting on your computer.

Comment: @Grant Yup, I want to remove them. Is it possible?

Comment: @Kyriosccs its not possible.

Comment: @Brendan In my view, I am using <input> type. It there anyway to format the input to show only ("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm--ss")?

Comment: Sure: `@Html.TextBox("name_of_input", Model.LastModifiedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"))` (substitute for whatever type of input you want to render)

Comment: Please reformulate your question to either "In the GUI I don't want to see X" or "I want to set X to zero"

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
model.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
```

or
    model.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.Today;

This doesn't technically remove the time from the date but it sets the time to 0 or 00:00, midnight. This should work for you.  Here is the documentation on the DateTime.Date property --> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

I think others commented that if you need to "hide" the time when output to a string use...

```
model.LastModifiedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
```